# Find files not containing search string

Tags: linux, shell, awk, grep, find

Is there a way to find out files of a type ,NOT containing a particular key-word.
This is both  -
1. under a particular directory
2. Under and particular directory and all underlying subdirectories.
Help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve this by something like

```
grep -L keyword $( find /start/path -type f )
```

You may need `GNU grep` for `-L`.

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation of [GNU grep](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/index.html)

You probably want

```
grep -L word file*
```

or

```
grep -Lr word dir/
```

Comment: `-lv` does not work in this case, you need to use `-L` to find out files that do not include pattern in them.

Comment: You also need to remove `-v`.